# devise google omniauth, redirects user to accounts.google.com after successfully signing in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, ruby-on-rails-5, google-signin, omniauth

I have integrated `sign in with google` functionality in my rails app using `gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'`.

But after a user successfully signs-in, it redirects the user to `accounts.google.com`.

Here are the logs:

```html
n_count" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "last_sign_in_at" = $3, "current_sign_in_ip" = $4, "updated_at" = $5 WHERE "users"."id" = $6  [["sign_in_count", 7], ["current_sign_in_at", "2020-11-21 07:32:51.801878"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2020-11-20 18:47:36.998385"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "111.119.178.141/32"], ["updated_at", "2020-11-21 07:32:51.807643"], ["id", 57]]
2020-11-21T07:32:51.822340+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2020-11-21T07:32:51.822224 #4] DEBUG -- : [7b2fe4de-297a-4155-b0e0-923b71d78386]    (8.9ms)  COMMIT
2020-11-21T07:32:51.827044+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2020-11-21T07:32:51.826967 #4] DEBUG -- : [7b2fe4de-297a-4155-b0e0-923b71d78386]   User Update (3.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "unique_session_id" = $1 WHERE "users"."id" = $2  [["unique_session_id", "ziqRhhsi2HtqsHBGGJpm"], ["id", 57]]
2020-11-21T07:32:51.827247+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2020-11-21T07:32:51.827162 #4] DEBUG -- : [7b2fe4de-297a-4155-b0e0-923b71d78386] [devise-security][session_limitable] unique_session_id=ziqRhhsi2HtqsHBGGJpm
2020-11-21T07:32:51.828443+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-11-21T07:32:51.828374 #4]  INFO -- : [7b2fe4de-297a-4155-b0e0-923b71d78386] Redirected to https://accounts.google.com/
2020-11-21T07:32:51.829252+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-11-21T07:32:51.829192 #4]  INFO -- : [7b2fe4de-297a-4155-b0e0-923b71d78386] Completed 302 Found in 46ms (ActiveRecord: 24.6ms)
```

here is the omniauth method:

```
@user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
      if @user.email.present?
        if @user.persisted?
          User.calculate_percentage(@user)
          sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication # this will throw if @user is not activated
          if is_navigational_format?
            set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Google')
          end
        else
          session[:omniauth] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except(:extra)
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
        end
      else
        session[:omniauth] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except('extra')
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: "Email can't be blank. Please Provide a valid Email Address."
      end
    end
```